# 'The name WebApplication does not exist in the current context' when swapping to ASP.Net 5 RC2

Tags: asp.net-core

When you make a new ASP.Net 5 application in Visual Studio you get this line at the end of your Startup.cs file

```cs
// Entry point for the application.
public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
```

(The class is `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebApplication`.)

If you replace `rc1-final` with `*` in the project.json file and thus pick up the latest RC2 the project no-longer builds, giving the error "The name WebApplication does not exist in the current context".

Looking at the [1.0.0.RC2 breaking changes](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+milestone%3A1.0.0-rc2) there is one titled [Hosting renaming WebApplication to WebHost](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/141). I cannot see how to take account of this change in the boiler-plate code. What line should replace the line of code above when swapping from ASP.Net 5 RC1 to RC2?

Comment: I've posted this as [an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/679) too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the latest packages, you must use `WebHostBuilder` instead of `WebApplication`. Here's [how you can use it](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.Server/Program.cs):

```
public static class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .ConfigureLogging(options => options.AddConsole())
            .ConfigureLogging(options => options.AddDebug())
            .UseDefaultHostingConfiguration(args)
            .UseIISPlatformHandlerUrl()
            .UseServer("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel")
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: So with that format do `Startup.ConfigureServices` and `Startup.Configure` still get called as before?

Comment: Sure, nothing changed in the way the Startup class works between RC1 and RC2.

Comment: I only see `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebApplicationBuilder` not `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebHostBuilder`. Will that do?

Comment: You're not using the latest RC2 packages then, because all the recent packages are now named `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*`.

Comment: Yes: replace all your `Microsoft.AspNet.*` packages by their `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` equivalent. You can read this ticket for more information: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/144.

Comment: So just changing lines in the project.json file like `"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final"` to `"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-*"` is not a good idea because I broke RC1 without getting RC2?

Comment: @dumbledad: When you do `"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-*"`, you will get an old RC2 version **BEFORE** the packages got renamed to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*`!!! It will probably pull bunch of old outdated RC2 packages that won't work with latest dnx/dotnet-cli.  It **has to be** `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-*"`

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason. It says `Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WebHostBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Link doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Comment: See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). This answer doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: you see this as answer if you dont like it please down-vote.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue

Comment: This solves the problem for DotNet6.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

1. Open your `projects.csproj` file with e.g., Notepad
2. You can add `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>` tag under:

   ```xml
   <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
     <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```