# ASP.NET Core Web API - The name 'WebApplication' does not exist in the current context WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I have this code in Program.cs of the WebApi Project:

**WebApi
Program.cs:**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I got this error:

> Error CS0103  The name 'WebApplication' does not exist in the current context WebApi

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288883/the-name-webapplication-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-when-swapping-to ?

Comment: In visual studio create new project and compare code with yours.

Comment: add using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually this happens when you have updated a .Net < 5 app to .Net 6. The reason is that you have to enable ImplicitUsings in the .csproj file

Makes sure the property group for your .csproj file contains this line in it:

```
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
```

Here is an example PropertyGroup from one of the recent projects where I upgraded from .Net Core 3.1 to .Net 6:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 11):

This also happens if you create a project and the Project SDK is not a Web SDK

In your project file:

Incorrect:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

Correct:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Answer (score 8):

Fully qualify it like this:

```
var builder = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message but this disappeared after changing  the TargetPackage from net7.0 to net6.0  in the cproj file

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```